# función para eliminar duplicados

Tags: r

Tengo estos 4 df

```
Pepe <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25),
col2 = c(98, 98, 98, 147, 147, 202, 202, 202, 235, 282, 293, 346, 358, 369, 414, 417, 440, 440, 540, 541, 545, 551)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-22L))
    
Juan <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 12, 13, 14,15, 26, 24, 18, 27,
25, 17, 19, 29, 21, 22, 30, 20, 28, 23, 34, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 40, 44, 42, 43, 39, 38),
col2 = c(213, 218, 228, 543, 543, 543, 543, 569, 1058, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1107, 1753, 
1755, 1760, 1761, 1762, 1782, 1796, 1802, 1810, 1948, 1950, 1957, 
1958, 1988, 2937, 2943, 2948, 3103, 3333, 3472, 3626, 3705, 3891, 
3928, 4124, 4140)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -39L))
    
Marta <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2), col2 = c(1507, 1723)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-2L))
    
denominador <- data.frame(Var1=c("Juan","Pepe","Marta"),min=c(67,121,118))
```

Los 3 primeros vienen dentro de una lista.

```
dat <- list()

dat[["Pepe"]] <- Pepe
dat[["Juan"]] <- Juan
dat[["Marta"]] <- Marta

rm("Juan","Marta","Pepe")
```

Entonces partimos de que tengo una lista con 3 df dentro y otro df llamado "denominador"

Primero pongo lo que quiero hacer paso a paso y luego con una función.

**Obtengo los df de la lista**

```
dat$Juan -> Juan
dat$Pepe -> Pepe
dat$Marta -> Marta
```

**Para "Juan" elimino los repetidos de la col2:**

```
aggregate(. ~ col2, Juan, head, 1, na.action = na.pass) -> Juan2
```

**El número de filas va a ser el numerador.**

```
nrow(Juan2) -> numerador_juan
```

**El denominador lo obtengo del df del mismo nombre.**

```
denominador[denominador$Var1 == "Juan","min"] -> deno_juan
```

**Hago lo mismo para "Pepe" y "Marta" .**

```
aggregate(. ~ col2, Pepe, head, 1, na.action = na.pass) -> Pepe2
nrow(Pepe2) -> numerador_pepe
denominador[denominador$Var1=="Pepe","min"] -> deno_pepe

aggregate(. ~ col2, Marta, head, 1, na.action = na.pass) -> Marta2
nrow(Marta2) -> numerador_marta
denominador[denominador$Var1=="Marta","min"] -> deno_marta
```

**Sumo todos los numeradores, los denominadores y los divido.**

```
numerador_juan + numerador_pepe + numerador_marta -> num

deno_juan + deno_pepe + deno_marta -> dem

num/dem*100
```

**Ahora quiero hacer lo mismo con una función**

Estaba haciendo pruebas de como sacar cada elemento por partes.

Como obtener los denominadores

```
names(dat)->nombres

demo=0
for (i in nombres){
  denominador[denominador$Var1 == i,"min"] -> deno1
  demo = demo + deno1
  print (demo)
}
```

Como obtener los numeradores.

```
for (i in nombres){
  aggregate(. ~ col2, i, head, 1, na.action = na.pass) -> nom1
  nrow(nom1) -> numerador_1
  print(numerador_1)
}
```

y aquí me da error. Creo que aggregate no acepta la i.

Comment: El problema, me parece, es que aggregate espera un data.frame e `i` simplemente es una cadena , creo que la cosa va por el lado de `aggregate(. ~ col2, dat[[i]], head, 1, na.action = na.pass)`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!